# spark - Calculating average of values in 2 or more columns and putting in new column in every row

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a Dataset/Dataframe with following contents:-

```
name, marks1, marks2
Alice, 10, 20
Bob, 20, 30
```

I want to add a new column which should have the average of column B and C.

Expected Result:-

```
name, marks1, marks2, Result(Avg)
Alice, 10, 20, 15
Bob, 20, 30, 25
```

for Summing or any other arithmetic operation I use `df.withColumn("xyz", $"marks1"+$"marks2")`. I cannot find a similar way for Average. Please help.

Additionally:- The number of columns are not fixed. Like sometimes it might be average of 2 columns, sometimes 3 or even more. So I want a generic code which should work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One of the easiest and optimized way is to *create a list of columns of marks columns* and use it with `withColumn` as

## pyspark

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

marksColumns = [col('marks1'), col('marks2')]

averageFunc = sum(x for x in marksColumns)/len(marksColumns)

df.withColumn('Result(Avg)', averageFunc).show(truncate=False)
```

and you should get

```
+-----+------+------+-----------+
|name |marks1|marks2|Result(Avg)|
+-----+------+------+-----------+
|Alice|10    |20    |15.0       |
|Bob  |20    |30    |25.0       |
+-----+------+------+-----------+
```

## scala-spark

the process is almost same in *scala* as done in *python* above

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, lit}

val marksColumns = Array(col("marks1"), col("marks2"))

val averageFunc = marksColumns.foldLeft(lit(0)){(x, y) => x+y}/marksColumns.length

df.withColumn("Result(Avg)", averageFunc).show(false)
```

which should give you same output as in *pyspark*

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: This solution is superior in performance, because it relies on vector calculations by Spark.

Answer (score 6):

It's as easy as using User Defined Functions. By creating a specific UDF to deal with average of many columns, you will be able to reuse it as many times as you want.

### Python

In this snippet, I'm creating a UDF that takes an array of columns, and calculates the average of it.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, array
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType

avg_cols = udf(lambda array: sum(array)/len(array), DoubleType())

df.withColumn("average", avg_cols(array("marks1", "marks2"))).show()
```

Output:

```
+-----+------+------+--------+
| name|marks1|marks2| average|
+-----+------+------+--------+
|Alice|    10|    20|    15.0|
|  Bob|    20|    30|    25.0|
+-----+------+------+--------+
```

### Scala

With the Scala API, you must process the selected columns as a Row. You just have to select the columns using the Spark `struct` function.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._
import scala.util.Try

def average = udf((row: Row) => {
  val values = row.toSeq.map(x => Try(x.toString.toDouble).toOption).filter(_.isDefined).map(_.get)
  if(values.nonEmpty) values.sum / values.length else 0.0
})

df.withColumn("average", average(struct($"marks1", $"marks2"))).show()
```

As you can see, I'm casting all any values to Double with `Try`, so that if the value cannot be casted, it won't throw any exception, performing the average only on those columns that are defined.

And that's all :)

Comment: This code needs to import 
scala.util.Try and org.apache.spark.sql.Row

I tried this, It shows 0.0 Average in all rows. Doesn't give me Actual Average. Please help.

Comment: I think it's because you need to cast to Int rather than Double. I have edited my answer @AkshatChaturvedi

Comment: @AkshatChaturvedi I've modified the answer casting the `Any` to `String` and then to `Double`. In this way, you will be able to calculate the average of many columns as you want, even if the the column types are different between them (for example, you can calculate the average of three column whose types are `String`, `Long` and `Double`, for instance).  And of course, you can reuse it whenever you want, just call the `avarage` function :)

Comment: Thank you. Both solutions working for me.